# Why am I unable to connect MATLAB Mobile to the MATLAB exe running on my computer?

Tags: matlab

I used matlab "connector" function to connect and get accelerometer data for count steps. It works properly in matlab. Then I created an exe and ran it. But it wasn't working. It shows an undefined variable or function "connector"

[image: matlab "connector"]